# Android webview does not display pages properly

Tags: android, webview

I'm using a webview to access a webpage, first time I ran it on my device (motorola xt1032 running KitKat) page loaded perfectly (was debugging on it, have internet permission on manifest), next time I ran it (now unplugged) it showed text only, no other components, now the funny thing is I ran it on an emulator (API 9) and it loaded correctly and continues to do so unlike my device (and other devices I've tried so far), code included below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_cultura_agenda);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_trans);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(res);
    WebView webCultEventos = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webCultAgenda);
    WebSettings webSettings = webCultEventos.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webCultEventos.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webCultEventos.loadUrl("http://culturacolima.gob.mx/v2/agenda-cultural/");
}
```

as for the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".CidecolMovilCultAgenda"
    android:id="@+id/laycultagenda" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webCultAgenda"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the webpage in loadUrl is the mobile version, tried the full version and it redirects to the mobile, but still loads text only. Any ideas why it loaded correctly 1st time only on devices? And why emulator works everytime? Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:

Tried multiple virtual machine configurations, they all loaded the page correctly, also got my hands on a device with API 9 and that one loaded correctly while other devices with higher APIs still won't work.